# field is immutable k8s

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy an application to GCP on kubernetes, however, the deployment fails with the error `the job spec is invalid ... the field is immutable`.

In the migration job, I have a section of bash in the following format:

```
args:
        - |
          /cloud_sql_proxy -instances=xxxxxxxxxxx:europe-west1:xxxxxxxxxxx=tcp:5432 -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json -log_debug_stdout=true &
          CHILD_PID=$!
          (while true; do echo "waiting for termination file"; if [[ -f "/tmp/pod/main-terminated" ]]; then kill ; echo "Killed  as the main container terminated."; fi; sleep 1; done) &
          wait 
          if [[ -f "/tmp/pod/main-terminated" ]]; then exit 0; echo "Job completed. Exiting..."; fi
```

but when the file is executed, in the yaml on GCP I see that the command has been enclosed in quotes and then it returns the above mention error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue was resolved. I had to wrap the values of the environment variables in the yaml file in quotes. That resolved the issue.

```
- name: DATABASE_URL:
  value: "${DATABASE_URL}"
```

Comment: Just have in mind that this is just one way to do it. Using '${DATABASE_URL}' or #DATBASE_URL ( <- which initially looks like a comment ) also is a possibility depending on the environment, since the last one obviously isn't correct yaml-syntax, but works in one of the environments I'm working on at the moment.

Answer (score 33):

I got the message `the job spec is invalid ... the field is immutable` for a different reason and wanted to briefly share it here.

I was trying to apply this yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: application-name
...
```

Turns out that this yaml was going to replace a previous version of the same Deployment. When I ran `kubectl get deployment application-name -o yaml` I saw this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: application-name
      track: stable
...
```

Apparently the `spec.selector.matchLabels` is currently an array, and I was trying to replace that with a single string. My fix was deleting the deployment and re-deploying it.

Comment: Thats what happened in my case too, removing the deployment fixed it.

Comment: It's not that it's an array, it's that you [_cannot_ change the selector for a Deployment by patching](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates), you have to delete and recreate it. My guess is that even though you were patching a extensions/v1beta1 Deployment, it was actually an app/v1 Deployment underneath (storage version migration), where that immutability was introduced.

Comment: @TBBIe's comment here solved the core problem for me. Doing a `kubectl delete <object_type> <object_name> -n <namespace>`, then doing a `kubectl apply` with my upgraded manifest, got me across the line.

Answer (score 10):

I got `field is immutable error` when I tried to run jobs in my cluster with the following command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f config.yml
```

where `config.yml` was defined as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-job-name
spec:
  # (...)
```

It worked for the first time, but the other ones with modified parameters did not.
Turned out the completed job was not deleted automatically and it still figured in the job list:

```bash
$ kubectl get jobs | grep my-job-name
my-job-name                                              1/1           4m29s      22h
```

So, you have to delete the old one as follows:

```
$ kubectl delete job my-job-name
```

Now you can send a new job with the same name using `kubectl apply -f config.yml`.

EDIT
As @CloudWatcher said in his comment, this can apparently hit different resource types. In his case, it was a secret that needed deletion.

Comment: This can apparently hit different resource types. In my case it was a secret that needed deletion.

Comment: @CloudWatcher good comment, I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [args](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod) in a Pod definition it's meant to be an array with single-string items. (It doesn't run the command in a shell) For example:

```
args:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy
        - -instances
        - ...
```

or

```
args:  [ "/cloud_sql_proxy", "-instances", "..." ]
```

The way to get around this is to [run the command in a shell](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell):

```
command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
args: 
        - -c
        - |
          /cloud_sql_proxy -instances=xxxxxxxxxxx:europe-west1:xxxxxxxxxxx=tcp:5432 -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json -log_debug_stdout=true &
          CHILD_PID=$!
          (while true; do echo "waiting for termination file"; if [[ -f "/tmp/pod/main-terminated" ]]; then kill ; echo "Killed  as the main container terminated."; fi; sleep 1; done) &
          wait 
          if [[ -f "/tmp/pod/main-terminated" ]]; then exit 0; echo "Job completed. Exiting..."; fi
```

The quotes(") on the array are for readability, they can be no quotes or single quotes(') too (As seen in the [YAML specs](https://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2570745))

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I am using, I just omitted that part in the question. But do you understand why the args are enclosed in double quotes in the yaml object?

Comment: The quotes are just for readability they can be double("), single(") or no quotes. Updated the answer.

Comment: When I check the yaml file on GCP after the job fails, I realize that the entire block of commands have been wrapped in quotes: